# Image expands outside of div after rotation

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've made a slideshow type container, but I'm having an issue where some of the pictures I add are rotated automatically by the browser, so I'm forced to rotate them using css properties. However, when I do this the image doesn't follow the div container styling. I've tried using javascript to transpose the height and width but the image aspect ratio changes.[image: examples]

```html
<div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-12" id="slides-container">
            <div  id="slide-show">
                <img  style="" src="{% static 'assets/reyhighdef.jpg' %}" alt="Photos of Rey">
                <img  class="rotate-img" src="{% static 'assets/IMG_1789.jpg' %}" alt="Photos of Rey">
                <img  style="" src="{% static 'assets/rumble_sign.jpg' %}" alt="Photos of Rey">
            </div>
            <div  id="buttons-container">
                <button id="button1"><h3><</h3></button>
                <button id="button2"><h3>></h3></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```css
#slide-show img {
    position:relative;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    justify-content: center;
}
#slides-container{
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 10px grey;
    background-color:black;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top:10vh;
}
#slide-show{
    text-align: center;
    height:60vh;
}
#buttons-container{
    padding: 10px 5% 0px 5%;
    width: 100%;
}
button h3{
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
#buttons-container button{
    cursor: pointer;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255, .75);
    border:0px;
}
button:active{
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 4px rgba(255,255,255, .9) inset;
}
button:focus{
    outline: none;   
}
#button1{
    float:left;
}
#button2{
    float:right;
}
```

```js
for(var i=0;i<$(".rotate-img").length;i++){
    var img = $(".rotate-img").eq(i);
    var w = $(img).width();
    var h = $(img).height();
    $(img).css({"height":w, "width":h, 'transform':'rotate(90deg)'});
}
```

Comment: what about using overflow: auto in your container, it forces the container to accept its content.

Comment: That sort of works, but the css format of the container still isn't being recognized because it creates a scrollbar

Comment: Now, add calculated width and height using javascript/jquery for your container.

Comment: It's better than before with overflow set to hidden, but the image still doesn't have the correct width/height

Comment: Can you please put your code in the snippet?

Comment: which code? the overflow:hidden? It might be misleading to add that when I have the example image. Hiding the overflow also doesn't solve the problem.